# Rails 5: Jquery autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have implemented the jquery autocomplete within my rails app.

And this is the setup:

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

items.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: "/search_suggestions",
        autoFocus: true,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $(event.target).val(ui.item.value);
            $('#search').closest("form").submit();
            return false;
       }
    });
});
```

this is the search action inside the model items.rb

```
  def self.search(term)
    return where("0=1") if term !~ /\w{4}/
    where("lower(title) LIKE lower(:term)", term: "%#{term}%")
  end
```

After that I created a search_suggestions resource:

```
rails g resource search_suggestion term popularity:integer
rails db:migrate
```

search_suggestions.rb

```
class SearchSuggestion < ApplicationRecord

  def self.terms_for(prefix)
    suggestions = where("term like ?", "#{prefix}_%")
    suggestions.order("popularity desc").limit(10).pluck(:term)
  end

  def self.index_items
    Item.find_each do |item|
      index_term(item.title)
      item.title.split.each { |t| index_term(t) }
    end
  end

   def self.index_term(term)
     where(term: term.downcase).first_or_initialize.tap do |suggestion|
     suggestion.increment! :popularity
     suggestion.save!
    end
  end
end
```

search_suggestions_controller.rb

```
  def index
    render json: SearchSuggestion.terms_for(params[:term])
  end
end
```

and I created the following rake task in order to update the search_suggestion index according to the setup I have inside the `search_suggestions.rb` model:

```
namespace :search_suggestions do
  desc "Generate search suggestions from items"
  task :index => :environment do
    SearchSuggestion.index_items
  end
end
```

and if I enter `rake search_sugegstions:index` the rake finishes without an error but doesn't update the table with the current items. For example there are still items that I have deleted and are still appearing inside the autocomplete.

Any ideas why this is happening? And is there a better way to implement this?

**Update1**

log/development.log when rake search_suggestions:index

Sorry for the format of this... the log was to big and thus I could not forma it properly.

`[1m[36mItem Load (1.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "items".* FROM "items" ORDER BY "items"."id" ASC LIMIT $1[0m  [["LIMIT", 1000]]
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (1.2ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "round"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 19]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "round"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 19]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (6.5ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.8ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.8ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[36mSearchSuggestion Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "search_suggestions"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["term", "rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "search_suggestions" SET "popularity" = COALESCE("popularity", 0) + 1 WHERE "search_suggestions"."id" = $1[0m  [["id", 20]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m`

Comment: Please show the relevant lines from your `log/development.log` file. (If you run `rake log:clear` before `rake search_suggestions:index`, you should just be able to post your entire log file.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Brian... I have update my question with the log... sorry for the format thought, the log is to big and I couldn't format it properly !

Comment: Your log indicates that the popularity of a single item ("rolex", id 20) is being incremented numerous times. Do you have more than one item in your database? Assuming you do, I suspect there's a problem with your `index_term` method. I'd suggest putting in some logging there to help discover the issue.