# Rails 5: Implement autocomplete according to database table

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to implement autocomplete according to the values created inside a table.

and this is the setup I have:

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

items.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: "/search_suggestions",
        autoFocus: true,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $(event.target).val(ui.item.value);
            $('#search').closest("form").submit();
            return false;
       }
    });
});
```

this is the search action inside the model items.rb

```
def self.search(term)
  return where("0=1") if term !~ /\w{4}/
  where("lower(title) LIKE lower(:term)", term: "%#{term}%")
end
```

after that I created a search_suggestions resource:

```
rails g resource search_suggestion term popularity:integer
rails db:migrate
```

search_suggestions.rb

```
class SearchSuggestion < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.terms_for(prefix)
    suggestions = where("term like ?", "#{prefix}_%")
    suggestions.order("popularity desc").limit(10).pluck(:term)
  end


  def self.index_terms(terms)
    terms.each do |term|
      where(term: term.downcase).first_or_initialize.tap do |suggestion|
        suggestion.increment! :popularity
        suggestion.save!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

search_suggestions_controller.rb

```
def index
  render json: SearchSuggestion.terms_for(params[:term])
end
```

app/services/index_items_service.rb

```
class IndexItemsService
  def call
    Item.find_each do |item|
      SearchSuggestion.index_terms([item.title].concat(item.title.split))
    end
    true
  end
end
```

and I created the following rake task in order to update the search_suggestion index according to the setup I have inside the search_suggestions.rb model:

```
namespace :search_suggestions do
  desc "Generate search suggestions from items"
  task :index => :environment do
    IndexItemsService.new.call
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :search_suggestions
```

and if I enter rake `search_sugegstions:index` the rake finishes without any errors and it does update the search_suggestion table database with all current items. But if I delete an item, the deleted item still appears inside the search_suggestion table database even after I run the rake command.

Any ideas how I can fix this error??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 5: Jquery autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47696204/rails-5-jquery-autocomplete)

Comment: @SRack... I never got to solve this one and I  would appreciate some help. I added this question in order for it to be more new and thus more visible for potential help. Thanks!

Comment: Anybody?.......

Comment: Have you tried using a `before_destroy` callback, to remove any search suggestions that shouldn't be there post-deletion? Re marking as duplicate, I think it's frowned upon to copy / paste an exact question if you haven't received an answer, and these are usually closed - it pollutes the database. More info on this in [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-one-of-my-own-questions-without-a-good-answer). Update the original with progress, or post a variation on the question with a little more research - that way people'll be able to help more readily :)